# document rating in SharePoint 2013 hosted app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, hosted-app

I have created a SharePoint 2013 hosted app though visual studio 2012. I configured a list to support document rating.

however, when I try to rate a document, I get the the following error:

---

Message from webpage

> The assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Proxy, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c does not support app
>   authentication.

Anyone has a solution ?

Thanks